# Power MOSFET versus regular MOSFET Silicon Layers

Tags: power, mosfet, process

I am having some difficulties differentiating between a power MOSFET process and a regular MOSFET process.  Here is a regular MOSFET silicon layer stackup:

[image]

The n+ doped region for the source and drain connection is exactly as I learnt it in classes back in the days with the oxide layer between the gate connection and the p-type silicon as a substrate.  No issues here.  What I am confused about is the Power MOSFET process and why you would use this process to get lower RDS(on), higher voltage, higher current, and so on.  Here is a picture of the Power MOSFET process:

[image]

As you can see, the drain is connected to the substrate of the die.  The source is the top side of the die and the gate takes a very small area of the top side.  There is a N- dope region between the drain and source that is confusing me.  Also, the process seems to be working in a vertical fashion instead of horizontal.  So here are my questions:

**1. Why would you want to use this process for a Power MOSFET?**
 **2. What are the advantages in terms of electrical characteristics?**

Comment: Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_MOSFET ? The section "Power MOSFETs have a different structure from the lateral MOSFET" is particularly relevant.

Comment: Also, in the "normal" process for lateral devices, many independent devices can be made so complex circuits can be made. That's not possible with the process for the vertical power MOSFET as the bulk is the drain of all the devices.

Comment: Basically, you make sure the channel region is distributed over the die to allow better heat dissipation. You also want your drain on the other side of the die, to have more space for source, gate and channel.

Comment: Usually the gate in a power MOSFET is laid out in some sort of a grid so that its effective width is very large. This allows the transistor to switch a lot of current.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Thank you for the insight.  Usually, what we can do is put two separate dies on a chip, one is a Power MOSFET and the other is the driver IC.

Comment: *put two separate dies on a chip* A die **is** a chip. What you mean is, two dies (chips) in **one package**. You need to have a good reason to do this btw as putting 2 dies in one package increases the chance of failure, if one of the two is broken you have to throw away both. Therefore I do not expect that there are many 2-dies-in-a-package products. At least, not that I know of.